# Source code from Apk using dex2jar getting error in command prompt

Tags: android, apk, dex2jar

I have to extract source code from APK file.  I had rename the apk file to zip file and use the command for `dex2jar classes.dex` to convert .dex file to jar.  But in command prompt getting error like:

> dex2jar is not an interanl or external command.

Downloaded dex2jar version.0.0.9 and extracted in new folder and extracted the new renamed APK file also in that folder.  But I got stuck with that.

Comment: But for this ,I can directly copy the classes.dex file to dex2jar batch file after that in the folder classes.dex.jar created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set your ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE correctly?? if not, dex2jar command should be executed from the same path where you extrcted dex2jar files. First change your command path to the folder where you extracted it, and then try firing your command, it should work.

Comment: I have directly copy the classes.dex files and paste into the dex2jar batch file i could got classes.dex2.jar file in the same folder.